# How to render a pipeline graph in Beam?

Tags: apache-beam

Using Apache Beam Python SDK version 2.9.0, is it possible to get a renderable pipeline graph representation similar to Google’s dataflow instead of running it?

I have difficulties to assemble complex pipelines and I would be happy to see an assembled pipeline before trying to execute it using `DirectRunner`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at this [unit test](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/runners/interactive/display/pipeline_graph_test.py). This should give you an example of how this works with Python SDK. [TextRenderer](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/runners/interactive/display/pipeline_graph_renderer.py#L72) simply returns the dot representation in text format.

There is also an explanation for how to do it and how to handle DOT files, but it is written for Java SDK ([link](https://mehmandarov.com/apache-beam-pipeline-graph/)). However, it should give you an idea how this can implemented, and the part about DOT files there is language agnostic.

You might also want to have a look at [PyDot](https://pypi.org/project/pydot/) package to see how to handle the output programmatically in Python.

Comment: Oh, nice! I forgot to answer my question with a custom solution where I was excavating info from the pipeline and building a graph using PyDot myself. But since there is already a fresh solution out of the box – this should be the accepted answer.